# is the image of a polynomial map contractible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-geometry

I asked this in MSE [is the image of a polynomial map contractible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643348/is-the-image-of-a-polynomial-map-contractible)

and got no response. Either it's a silly question or I posted it under the wrong category. In either case, feedback would be appreciated. Here is the question:

There are often questions in differential geometry asking if a certain manifold has a polynomial parametrization. Are there topological obstructions to existence of such parametrization? More precisely, if we have a polynomial map $f:U\rightarrow R^m$ (and suppose $U$ is an open disk $\mathbb{R}^n$), is the image of $f$ always contractible? I can't think of a counter-example. Maybe algebraic geometers can help? I'm thinking if perhaps every rational affine variety is contractible?

Comment: Consider the polynomial map $f:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}^2$, $t\mapsto(t^2-1,t(t^2-1))$. (See the picture on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve .) The image is not contractible.

Comment: What if we impose the condition that the image of f is smooth?

Comment: $(t^2-1 + (3t^2-t) x , t(t^2-1) + 2t x )$ for $t$ in some large-enough interval and $x$ in some small enough interval. This is just an open neighborhood of Sasha's example. Because it's an open subset of $R^2$, it's smooth, but it still has the same topology.

Comment: @Sasha Anan'in: thank you! can we say that this cubic is not contractible even as a variety (the zero locus of $y^2-x^3$) in the complex plane?

Comment: @abrido the cubic is given by $y^2=x(x^2+1)$ (In order to see that it is not contractible, please look at the indicated picture.)

Comment: @SashaAnan'in: yes, that's what I meant. but the picture is  in the real plane. so I'm asking if the loop remains a loop in the complex plane?

Comment: @abrido In complex plane, the picture is similar: it is ${\mathbb C}$ with two distinct points identified; so, the fundamental group of the image is still ${\mathbb Z}$.